# Connect to ALM 12

Tags: excel, vba, alm

I am trying to connect Excel to ALM 12.21.

The code fails at the login step and throws an error message stating "Failed to Login" irrespective of providing the correct Username and Password.

I am trying to connect to HP ALM 12.2x

```
Sub ConnectToQC()

Dim sUserName = <Username>
Dim sPassword = <pwd>
Dim QCConnection
Set QCConnection = CreateObject("TDEApiOle80.TDConnection")
QCConnection.InitConnectionEx "http://hp-alm.123.com/qcbin"
QCConnection.Login sUserName, sPassword

**If(QCConnection.LoggedIn <> True) Then**
    **MsgBox Err.Description**
    End
End If

'<Rest of the Code...>
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to the ALM Connectivity add-in is either not installed/incorrect version.

1. Navigate to http://hp-alm.123.com/qcbin
2. Click on Addons
3. Install ALM Connectivity Addin

Also, when you are building the integration the first time, don't wrap your code inside `On Error Resume Next` which suppresses all the errors and may be hard to debug the actual cause of the problem.